# how to perform matrix in sas using any function or array

Tags: sas

I have two table table A and table B.in table A there are 3 columns and 3 observation  and in table B I have 1 column and 3 observation . So I want to multiply each value of column to the row of table A.
Example

```
Data A ;
Input a b c;
Datalines;
1 2 3
4 5 6
1 2 6
;
Run;

Data B;
Input a;
Datalines;
7
8
4
;
Run;
```

So I want to multiply 7 * 1 then 8*2 then 4 * 3 
7*4 then 8 *5 then 4*6 and so on.how to achieve this.Suppose there are 180 columns in table A and 180 rows in table B

Comment: What do you want out?  Do you want for the first row of A to produce a row like 7,16,12 ?  Or a single value like 7+16+12?  Do you have SAS/IML licensed?

Answer (score 1):

To perform a matrix product in DATA Step you can use arrays.  The column vector is loaded into a temporary array for application against each row in the data set:

```
data product (keep=a_prod_b);
  array vector(3) _temporary_;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    do _index = 1 to dim(vector);
      set b;
      vector(_index) = a;
    end;
  end;

  set a;
  array row a b c; * replace with v1-v180 or the 180 column names;

  a_prod_b = 0;
  do _index = 1 to dim (row);
    a_prod_b + row(_index) * vector(_index);
  end;
run;
```

Partial products

```
data partials;
  array vector(3) _temporary_;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    do _index = 1 to dim(vector);
      set b;
      vector(_index) = a;
    end;
  end;

  set a;
  array row a b c;

  do _index = 1 to dim (row);
    row(_index) = row(_index) * vector(_index);
  end;

  drop _index;
run;
```

For the case of 180 columns I would presume the column names are indexed such as `v1` to `v180`.